# Powershell Wrapping using Winexe / Linux

Tags: bash, powershell, winexe

This is the powershell command which works fine under windows powershell cli.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\backup -Recurse | 
     Where-Object {$_.length -gt 1GB} | 
        Sort-Object -Property Length |
            Format-Table  Name,@{name='Size GB';expression={$_.length/1GB}; FormatString='N2'}
```

Is there any way I can execute this command using from linux like using WINEXE? howto wrap it?

```
winexe -U DC/ID%"PASSWORD" //10.0.0.1 'powershell.exe -command "Get-ChildItem -Path c:\backup -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.length -gt 1GB} |  Sort-Object -Property Length | Format-Table  Name,@{name='Size GB';expression={$_.length/1GB}"'
```

Comment: [How to escape single-quotes within single-quoted strings?](//stackoverflow.com/a/16605140) ?

Comment: Thanks 
Following worked

** '"'"' **

Comment: Full command as follows...
`
winexe -U DC/ID%"PASS" //10.0.0.0 'powershell.exe -command "Get-ChildItem -Path c:\backup -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.length -gt 1KB} | Sort-Object -Property Length | Format-Table  Name,@{name='"'"'Size KB'"'"';expression={$_.length/1KB};FormatString='"'"'N2'"'"'}"'
`